# Playorm cannot retrieve data populated using cql3

Tags: cql3, playframework-2.3, playorm

I am using playorm version 1.7 , cassandra 2.0.10 , playframework 2.3. I can easily retrieve any data from tables that were created using playorm/thrift. But if I try to retrieve any data from a table that was created using cql3 shell, it fails. It doesn't recognize there is a table by the requested name. But it cant even add the table as it already exists.

InvalidRequestException(why:Cannot add already existing column family "account.

I am surely missing something ?

Comment: Add me as an interested party on this question. I've got quite a few large populated tables, and we would like to use playorm to upgrade our existing apps.

I get the same error as above, and when looking at the debug log, can clearly see lookup failures on the existing cf's.

Thank you